# The average of a random varible with pdf in the form of an parametric inegral

Tags: expected-value

The pdf of a random variable $T$  in the interval $(0,1)$ in a certain problem I was trying to solve is given by :
$$ g(t)= c\int_{0}^{1-t} t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1} d u $$ where c is some constant.We know the average $E(T)$ is given by :

$$E(T)=\int_0^1t g(t) dt.$$ In order to evaluate this integral I tried integration by parts by taking $g(t)$ as the first function and calculating $g'(t)$ .It however did not help.I want to know if there is some way of calculating the above integral for the expectation of T.I would highly appreciate if somebody could help me with this integral.\
**PS:** To be specific ,$g(t)$ is the range of the distances from origin of n *iid* points in the n-dimensional ball and $c=m^2n(n-1)$

Comment: This effort is likely to be fruitless (these integrals are obviously polynomials in $t$ and, absent some miraculous cancellation, will have degrees that are $O(mn)$): consider obtaining asymptotic expressions if your interest is in large $m,$ large $n,$ or both.